# Declaring int i at the beginning of the program vs in for loop

Tags: c++

What would be the difference of declaring i at the beginning of the program

```
int a, b, c, i;
```

vs in the for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<=n;i++)?
```

I developed a habit to declare it in the for loop and I don't know if that's fine (I'm better at JS and I encountered many problem in my programs because of this, but in C++ I didn't.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you define "beginning of the program" more clearly? Are we talking functional scope/ global scope/etc. ?

Comment: Minimize the scope of your variables, irrespective of the language. You'll have a better time.

Comment: You are doing the right thing. Variables should have the smallest scope possible.It helps preserve locality of reference. I can't tell you how many times I've seen variables declared at the beginning of a function which were never used anywhere in the function-- they had once been used, but no longer were. Never declare a variable until you have a valid, meaningful value to put in it.

Comment: @mascoj int main()
{
 int a[50][100], n, m, i, j;
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
 {
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
  {
   cin >> a[i][j];
  }
 }
    return 0;
} vs int main()
{
 int a[50][100], n, m;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
  {
   cin >> a[i][j];
  }
 }
    return 0;
}

Comment: @mascoj can't format it properly because it's a comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: @erip so I'm actually doing the right thing, I suppose.

Comment: Edit that code into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

Most of the time it's OK to use

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { ... }
```

However, sometimes you want to know the value of `i` when the loop ended. In that case, you would need to declare the variable before the for loop.

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i <= n && (some other tests); i++ ) { ... }

// Do different things based on the value of i.
if ( i == n+1 )
{
   dothis();
}
else
{
   dothat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope problem. If you define `int a` before the loop, you can use it in and outside the loop. When you define it inside the loop you can only use it inside the loop.

Here is a nice article about Scope in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662.aspx)

ps.: Your loop doesn't work, unless you define and initalize the `n` variable

Comment: Yes, I know, that was just an example. Thanks for the useful link though!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you don't need `i` after the loop (the scope will only be the for loop) then declare it in the for loop.  If you need it after the loop (the scope is the block of code your in) then you must declare it outside and before the loop.

Comment: Okay, so when I don't need i after the loop it's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When int i is declared outside the for loop, it can be accessed outside the for loop and inside but when you define it inside the loop, it can only be used inside the loop. Usualy, if you need it for the for loop define it inside the loop.